# If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f(x) \neq f'(x)$, show that $\{x\in [0,1] \text{ and } f(x) = 0\}$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f(x) \neq f'(x)$ for all $x$, show that $\{x\in [0,1]  \text{ and } f(x) = 0\}$ is finite.

I have shown that there cannot be an interval $[a,b]$ contained in $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ since this would imply that $f$ is constant on this interval which implies that $f'(x) = 0$ on this interval and so there is contradiction since for $x\in [a,b], f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 0$ since the interval is constant, but $f(x) \neq f'(x)$ for all $x$.

However I can't prove that for some infinite sequence $\{x_n\}$, say the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ the statement holds true.

Comment: What topological properties do you know about [0,1]? ​ ​

Comment: That it is compact (since closed and bounded)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use that an infinite sequence of zeros would have a converging subsequence, since $[0,1]$ is compact. The limit $x$ of this subsequence fulfills $f(x)=0=f'(x)$.

Comment: How come the derivative must also be 0?

Comment: $f$ is a priori differentiable, so you can compute the derivative at $x$ by approaching $x$ with any sequence you like. For example the converging subsequence...

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Countable Choice [would be needed](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.311.1929&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to go from "is no infinitely sequence of distinct" to "are only finitely many". $\;$

Comment: The fact that the natural numbers admit an injection into any infinte set is a direct consequence of the peano axioms, isn't it? No countable choice needed.

Comment: @Moos : $\;\;\;$ It's definitely not. $\:$ The _natural_ argument (for each n, choose an element that wasn't previously chosen) in fact uses [dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice), although one can get the result with just [Countable Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice). $\:$ (For each n, choose an ordered (n+1)-tuple of distinct elements, and then map n to the leftmost entry of the (n+1)-tuple which isn't mapped to by any smaller natural number.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Choosing one single element from a set is not using choice.

Comment: However, choosing an infinite sequence of elements can easily be using choice. $\;$

Answer (score 4):

If $X = \{x\in [0,1] \mid f(x)=0\}$ is infinite, then $X$ has a limit point $\bar x \in [0,1]$. By continuity, $f(\bar x) = 0$. By differentiability,
$$
f'(\bar x) = \lim_{\substack{
         x \to \bar x\\ x\in X\setminus\{\bar x\}}}
         \frac {f(x)-f(\bar x)} {x - \bar x} = 
         \lim_{\substack{
         x \to \bar x\\ x\in X\setminus\{\bar x\}}}
         \frac 0 {x - \bar x} = 0,
$$
so $f(\bar x) = f(\bar x)$, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: One can [avoid Countable Choice](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.311.1929&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by directly using that $\overline{x}$ is a limit point, rather than asserting the existence of a sequence. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I took your suggestion. I have no aversion to countable or dependent choice, but you're right, there's no need to conjure a sequence here.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, we can even show that $f$ has at most one root on $\mathbb{R}$.

To the contrary, assume that we have two zeros, $x_0 < x_2$. Since $f'(x_0) \ne 0$, we may assume (w.l.o.g.) that $f'(x_0) > 0$.
Now we set $x_1 = \inf\{z > x_0 : f(z) = 0\}$. We easily get $f(x_1) = 0$ (by continuity) and $x_1 > x_0$ since $f'(x_0) > 0$.

Now we have $f'(x_1) \ne 0$ and by the intermediate value theorem we can conclude $f'(x_1) < 0$. Now, we define the function $g(z) = f(z) - f'(z)$ and have $g(x_0) < 0 < g(x_1)$. This $g$ is the derivative of $\int f \,\mathrm{d}x - f$. By owing to [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)), we find some $z \in (x_0,x_1)$ with $g(z) = 0$, i.e., $f(z) = f'(z)$, which is a contradiction to the assumption.